# Are curly apostrophes valid when declaring strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm reviewing some code which has this...

```
var id = ‘648’;
```

instead of this...

```
var id = '648';
```

Obviously I'd prefer the latter, but is the first example technically valid? Or more importantly, would any browser error out with this?

Comment: @chris eaxctly, that's my point.

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals).

Comment: They probably used a word processor to write code, ugh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, those are illegal.  From Chrome console:

```
var id = ‘648’;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Word is not an IDE.

Comment: @FelixKling It's better than Word!

Comment: Ah, my mistake, the code I was looking at was not showing an error in the console, but that's because the error was being eaten for other reasons. Once I isolated the code, I saw the same error.